# Is it possible to define a command in bash?

Tags: bash, command-line, cd-command

For example, can I set:

```
gb = cd /media/Dan/evolution
```

... so that every time I execute `gb` in bash, I can `cd` to that particular directory?

I found something online: the `alias` command. But it seems that it can't do the work above.

Is it possible to do it? How?

Comment: `alias gb='cd /media/Dan/evolution'`

Comment: @Zen, please accept the answer if it resolves the issue. This is a gesture of saying thank you to the user who helped you in resolving the issue :)

Comment: Note: This is about bash: Linux is a kernel. Linux is often, incorrectly, used to refer to the whole operating system. This can result in confusion. For instance the question “can I do such and such thing under Linux?” is if you can do it on some computer then yes. Because you could implement any operating system you like using a Linux kernel. So we need to know which one, you are using Ubuntu Gnu+Linux+probably X11(if on a desktop ie not a server without a display).

Comment: @richard Good point, though technically this is `posix` complaint, so not just `bash`.

Comment: @richard Not "incorrectly" per se.  It's a well-established term. The systems do have a lot in common, in general. Note that I'm referring to the concept of "Linux" as a bunch of OS's.

Comment: @keyser yes it is well established (Linux to mean a whole operating system), and that is a pity. Android is Linux, but can you define an alias on Android. Android and Gnu+Linux are not the some OS.

Comment: @keyser I hate to be picky, but you say as the first thing that you say on this thread (or anywhere else on Unix & Linux) “I'm referring to the concept of "Linux" as a bunch of OSs”, when did you refer?

Comment: @richard Indeed, that's the problem. It works since people don't mean Android and such flavors, more or less. I'm not saying it's a good thing, but it is what it is. My referral was implicit since I was commenting on your linux statement. I was just making myself clear since the subject was the confusing term. (I might've misunderstood your last comment)

Comment: +1 @keyser for “I'm not saying it's a good thing, but”, it is confusing though: when we read about Linux we don't know which meaning is being used, and may not even be aware that 2 meanings are often used.

Comment: @keyser, where you logged in as a different user before. You seem to have popped out of nowhere.

Comment: @richard Haha no :p What do you mean? I just stumbled upon this thread while browsing the SE network

Answer (score 51, accepted):

just type:

```
alias gb='cd /media/Dan/evolution'
```

To make this setting permanent (so that it sticks after you restart or open another console) add this line to the file ~/.bashrc (assuming you use the bash as your default shell)

Comment: To make it even more nice, you could create a dedicated alias file for your aliasses, say ~/.bash_aliases, and call it from within your ~/.bashrc file like this:

[ -e ~/.bash_aliases ] && . ~/.bash_aliases

This way, you don't "pollute" the ~/.bashrc file with other stuff.

Answer (score 42):

Alternative to aliasing

```
gb() { cd /media/Dan/evolution; }
```

This defines shell function gb, which takes no arguments, and performs cd /media/Dan/evolution. As with other suggeststions, this can be added to ~/.bashrc

Comment: With the disadvantager that the alias command shows the defined alias, afaik defining such a function can result in "unexpected behaviour". I will vote up thou for the sake of completness :)

Comment: Not really. You can just type: declare -f gb to see what it does

Comment: Also, this option is more flexible in that it allows you to add your *custom* logic within the function definition to accept arguments and do whatever you need. Aliases only allows passing arguments and doing *predefined actions*.

Comment: @PaulCalabro Even better, `type gb` will work if it's an alias *or* a function.

Comment: POSIXLY: `{ echo 'true() { : ; }' >./script ; . ./script ; command -V true ; command -V /usr/bin/true ; }` - `true is a shell function\n/usr/bin/true is /usr/bin/true` - the `\n` characters were literal newlines in the output.

Answer (score 11):

It is possible, and `alias` is the command you're looking for. For example `alias ll="ls -l"` in bash will let you type `ll` instead of `ls -l`. Please note there are no spaces used when setting an alias. `man alias` can be useful as well.

Answer (score -3):

Alternatively, it is possible to write a C program that calls the desired command and save it to /usr/bin.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
    char command[50]; //notice you can change this to fit your needs
    int return_val;

    strcpy( command, "echo \"cd /media/Dan/evolution\" | bash -i" );
    return_val = system(command); 

   //this is equivalent to entering the command in a new bash, 
   //which will return and exit

    return return_val;
}
```

To compile it, go to the directory where the source was saved (in bash) and execute (you may need sudo):

```
 gcc ./gb.c -o /usr/bin/gb
```

After further research [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-208754.html), I realized simply throwing your command in `system()` won't work for bash built in commands. That's why you need to create an instance of an interactive bash and echo your commands to it. It's just overly complicated and probably useless, unless you want to, let's say, shorten a call to a shell script (`some_script` instead of `sh ~/radgeRayden/Scripts/some_script`).

[Reference for the system() function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_system.htm)

Comment: Did you actually try this? It doesn't work.

Comment: No, unfortunately I'm not near my linux machine right now. But I'll try it later and report back. I've used C programs as bash aliases before, though. What didn't work exactly?

Comment: For the same reason that `sh -c "cd /media/Dan/evolution"` doesn't work.  Hint: subshell

Comment: `cd`/subshell issues aside, what is the advantage in wrapping a shell command in c program, when you could just as easily (or more easily) put that command in a shell script?

Comment: No advantage, really. I used it before knowing about alias and thought extra info wouldn't hurt. After further research [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-208754.html), I noticed the subshell thing, and the fact it exits after the command. At this point, you're just writing a shell script inside a C program.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect the acknowledgements.

Comment: Not an expert at this, but shouldn't something like this (hopefully, something more useful) be put in /usr/local/bin?

Comment: Probably. I am not aware of many best practices, just tinker a lot with a machine I don't care very much about the integrity.

Comment: Even if this COULD work it should not go into /usr/local/bin as it is specific to the one user.